# Axios is defined but never used

Tags: vue.js, axios

After I import axios `import axios from "axios";` in my `App.vue` file, I got `axios is defined but never used` error. I attached the error image and `package.json` code. I installed `axios`. How to fix it ?[image]

The package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "myvue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^3.6.95",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",

    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: this is most likely caused by a linter

Comment: The solution is to use `axios`. [Please don't post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Maybe duplicated line, or mostly you did not use it to create a request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more of a warning than an error, but it's set to be an error in your `eslint` file .

It's just saying you didn't use `axios` but you imported it. That lint rule just makes sure you're using every variable you have defined.

Here's the docs on that rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

Answer (score 13):

You can solve this by updating your `package.json` file, under `"eslintConfig"` like:

```
...

"rules": {
  "no-console": "off",
  "no-unused-vars": "off"
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using it anywhere in your App.vue file.

Remove that import and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Goto `package.json` file find `eslintConfig` include `rules` object with following properties.

```json
"eslintConfig": {
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "no-console": [
      "warn",{ "allow":[ "clear", "info", "error", "dir", "trace", "log"]}
    ],
  }
},
```

> **no-unused-vars**
> This rule report variable definitions of v-for directives or scope attributes if those are not used.